# How to create a Hashmap in Scala with key as String and value as another String or another Hashmap

Tags: java, json, scala, dictionary

I want to create a variable in Scala which can have data of the following format:

```
"one" -> "two",
"three -> {"four" -> "five", "six -> "seven"},
"eight" -> {"nine" -> { "ten" -> "eleven", "twelve" -> "thirteen"},
           "fourteen" -> {"fifteen" -> "sixteen}
           }
```

I tried creating a Java HashMap using:

```
var requiredVar = new HashMap[String, Object]()
```

I am able to do something like :

```
var hm = new HashMap[String, String]
hm.put("four","five")
requiredVar.put("three",hm)
```

But if I try to add :

```
requiredVar.get("three").put("six","seven")
```

I get the error that

> value put is not a member of Object

How can I get this done?

I have tried something like native to Scala as well:

```
val a = Map("one" -> "two" , "three" -> Map("four"->"five"))
a.get("three").put("six"->"seven")
```

but get the following error:

> error: value put is not a member of Option[Any]

Comment: Either use `.asInstanceOf` or introduce a hierarchy (algebraic data type) instead of Object: `sealed trait A` `case class B(s: String) extends A` `case class C(m: Map[String, String]) extends A` `case class D(mm: Map[String, Map[String, String]]) extends A`, you have a `Map[String, A]`, you can use pattern matching

Comment: You should not be using `var` or mutable collections, that's not really how you write code in scala. You should also, probably, read some basic intro about the language and type system. `requiredVar.get("three").put("six","seven")` -- you declared values of this map to be `Object`,  so, you can't `put` things there. 
`val a = Map("one" -> "two" , "three" -> Map("four"->"five"))` -- you should not be mixing types like this. `a` ends up being `Map[String, Any]`, so you can't `put` anything into value without casting again. Also, `Map.get` returns an `Option`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, when using Java, you get the error because the compiler doesn't know that the value that retrieved from `requiredVar` is a `Map`.
You declare `requiredVar` to be a `HashMap[String, Object]`, so the compiler will only know anything retrieved from the map is an `Object`, nothing more specific.

Specifically, in your case:

`requiredVar.get("three").put("six","seven")`

`requiredVar.get("three")` returns an `Object`, which doesn't have a `put()` method.

You are running into a similar issue in the Scala version of your code as well. When you create the `Map`:

`val a = Map("one" -> "two" , "three" -> Map("four"->"five"))`

the compiler must infer the types of the keys and values, which it is doing by finding the closest common ancestor of all the values, which for a `String` and another `Map`, is `Any`, Scala's equivalent to Java's `Object`. So when you try to do

`a.get("three").put("six"->"seven")`

`a.get("three")` is returning an `Option[Any]`, which doesn't have a `put` method. By the way, Scala's `Map.get` returns an `Option`, so that if the key is not present in the map, a `None` is returned instead an exception being thrown. You can also use the more concise method `a("three")`, which returns the value type directly (in this case `Any`), but will throw an exception if the key is not in the map.

There are a few ways I can think of try to achieve what you want to do.

**1) Casting**

If you are absolutely sure that the value you are retrieving from the map is another `Map` instead of a `String`, you can cast the value:

```scala
requiredVar.get("three").asInstanceOf[HashMap[String, String]].put("six","seven")
```

This is a fairly brittle approach, as if the value is a `String`, then you will get a runtime exception thrown.

**2) Pattern Matching**

Rather than casting arbitrarily, you can test the retrieved value for its type, and only call `put` on values you know are maps:

```scala
requiredVar.get("three") match {
  case m: HashMap[String, String] => m.put("six", "seven")
  case _ => // the value is probably a string here, handle this how you'd like
}
```

This allows you to guard against the case that the value is not a map. However, it is still brittle because the value type is `Any`, so in the `case _` case, you don't actually know the value is a `String`, and would have to pattern match or cast to know for sure and use the value as a `String`

**3) Create a new value type**

Rather than rely on a top type like `Object` or `Any`, you can create types of your own to use as the value type. Something like the following could work:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

sealed trait MyVal 
case class StringVal(s: String) extends MyVal
case class MapVal(m: Map[String, String]) extends MyVal

object MyVal {
  def apply(s: String): StringVal = StringVal(s)
  def apply(m: Map[String, String]): MapVal = MapVal(m)
}

var rv = Map[String, MyVal]()
rv += "one" -> MyVal("two")
rv += "three" -> MyVal(Map[String, String]("four" -> "five"))

rv.get("three") match {
  case Some(v) => v match {
    case MapVal(m) => m("six") = "seven"
    case StringVal(s) =>  // handle the string case as you'd like
  }
  case None => // handle the key not being present in the map here
}
```

The usage may look similar, but the advantage now is that the pattern match on the `rv.get("three")` is complete.

**4) Union types**

If you happen to be using a 3.x version of Scala, you can use a union type to specify exactly what types of values you will have in your map, and achieve something like the above option much less verbosely:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

val rv: Map[String, String | Map[String, String]] = Map()
rv += "one" -> "two"
rv += "three" -> Map[String, String]("four" -> "five")
rv.get("three") match {
  case Some(m: Map[String, String]) => m += "six" -> "seven"
  case Some(s: String) => // handle string values
  case None => // handle key not present
}
```

One thing to note though, with all of the above options, is that in Scala, it is preferable to use immutable collections, instead of mutable versions like `HashMap` or `scala.collection.mutable.Map` (which is by default a `HashMap` under the hood). I would do some research about immutable collections and try to think about how you can redesign your code accordingly.